# Failed to install Ruby gem curb on windows 8

Tags: ruby, curl

I'm trying to install the curb gem on windows 8 but it returns errors. I was also trying by providing option like --with-curl-dir, --with-curl-lib, --with-curl-include but not working. Every time it return the error.Please give any suggestion. Thanks

```
C:\Users>gem install curb -- --with-curl-lib=C:/curl-7.21.0-devel-mingw32/bin --with-curl-include=C:/curl-7.21.0-devel-mingw32/include
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing curb:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-curl-lib=C:/curl-7.21.0-devel-mingw32/bin --with-curl-include=C:/curl-7.21.0-devel-mingw32/include
checking for curl-config... no
checking for main() in -lcurl... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby
        --with-curl-dir
        --without-curl-dir
        --with-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
        --with-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
        --with-curllib
        --without-curllib
extconf.rb:23:in `<main>':   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)

  Try passing --with-curl-dir or --with-curl-lib and --with-curl-include
  options to extconf.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/curb-0.8.6 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/curb-0.8.6/ext/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have **curl library** installed on you machine in root directory then try following command in command prompt

> gem install curb -v 0.8.6 --platform=ruby -- --with-curl-lib=C:/curl-7.34.0-devel-mingw32/bin --with-curl-include=C:/curl-7.34.0-devel-mingw32/include